# command line using string.Format() to handle escape characters

Tags: c#, string, command-line, escaping, string-formatting

Thank for reading my thread.

Here is the command line I like to call within my C# code:

```
C:\>"D:\fiji-win64\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe" -eval "run('Bio-Formats','open=D:\\Output\\Untitiled032\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif display_ome-xml')"
```

This is the exact command I can see from my console window, and it runs and gives me what I need. I want to run this command line from from my C# code, so there is escape character problem I don;t know how to handle

There are two strings I'd like to make them flexible

1. D:\fiji-win64\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe
2. D:\Output\Untitiled032\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif

I am wondering how I can use `string.Format()` to formulate this command line?

This is my current code, it opens the image, but the `display_ome-xml` did not get called:

```
string bioformats = "Bio-Formats";
string options = string.Format("open={0} display_ome-xml", fileName.Replace("\\", "\\\\"));

string runCommand = string.Format("run(\"'{0}'\",\"'{1}'\")", bioformats, options);
string fijiCmdText = string.Format("/C \"\"{0}\" -eval {1}", fijiExeFile, runCommand);
```

where `fijiExeFile` works fins, it is just the `runCommand` keeps ignoring the `display_ome-xml`. Anyone has any suggestions? It is really really confusing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would try to remove all of those \", they don't seems to be needed neither in the exe name or in the parameters. Also, remove that double replace("\\", "\\\\")

Comment: How exactly are you passing the parameters into the `C#` program?

Comment: load the string from xml

Comment: Also, where is the code that actually runs the command? If you show that, it will be easier to tell why `display_ome-xml` is ignored.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(); startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

                    startInfo.Arguments = fijiCmdText;
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.Start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kristian pointed out, `@` can help here. It also appears that there may be some extra or misplaced `\"` in the code above. This seems to give the desired output string:

```
string fijiExeFile = @"D:\fiji-win64\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe";
string fileName = @"D:\\Output\\Untitiled032\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif";

string bioformats = "Bio-Formats";
string options = string.Format("open={0} display_ome-xml", fileName);

string runCommand = string.Format("run('{0}','{1}')", bioformats, options);
string fijiCmdText = string.Format("\"{0}\" -eval \"{1}\"", fijiExeFile, runCommand);
```

Comment: fileName is a string variable, when it is retrieved, it seems it is already in the format of D:\\Output\\Untitled032\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif

Comment: OK I have edited my code to eliminate the `.Replace` since the double `\` are already present. You can disregard my first two lines if the fijiExeFile or fileName values are already coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the verbatim string literal.
Just put a @ before your string like so:

```
@"c:\abcd\efgh"
```

This will disable the backslash escape character

If you need " inside your string, you will have to escape the the quotation marks like so:

```
@"c:\abcd\efgh.exe ""param1"""
```

Your example could be:

```
String.Format(@"""{0}"" -eval ""run('Bio-Formats','open={1} display_ome-xml')""", @"D:\fiji-win64\Fiji.app\ImageJ-win64.exe", @"D:\Output\Untitiled032\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif")
```

or

```
string p1 = "D:\\fiji-win64\\Fiji.app\\ImageJ-win64.exe";
string p2 = "D:\\Output\\Untitiled032\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif";

String.Format(@"""{0}"" -eval ""run('Bio-Formats','open={1} display_ome-xml')""", p1, p2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you can see, I am really inexperienced at this, so any chance you can extend your answer a little more by writing my command line out using string.Format()? In that way at least I can get some education.

Comment: What if the fileName is a string variable, when it is retrieved, it seems it is already in the format of D:\\Output\\Untitled032\\ChanA_0001_0001_0001_0001.tif ?

Comment: That's fine, you can just pass it as a parameter to the String.Format

Comment: Not working, it does not even start D:\\fiji-win64\\Fiji.app\\ImageJ-win64.exe

Comment: Sounds strange, how does the final string look like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52711/discussion-between-kristian-hebert-and-ono)

Comment: @kristan  Sorry, I am back here; But it seems that the string has to start with  "/C  in the command line, other wise it is not going to raise the application

Comment: Kristian: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think it is very close, but the other one simply works. I am upvoting you, and thanks for being so supportive.